# Will changing site to HTTPS and updating AdWords cause me to lose my quality scores?

Tags: google-ads

Will changing my site URL from HTTP to HTTPS and updating AdWords to use the HTTPS version cause all my ads to lose their quality scores?

Comment: As a side note, I ran across this [article](http://feeds.searchengineland.com/~r/searchengineland/~3/RQE_JseGptg/when-migrating-from-http-to-https-google-says-to-use-301-redirects-304200) today right after reading your question.  It explains how Google recommends to use 301 redirects when migrating from HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted, seems a reasonable question, if it isnt please advise why not so it can be changed

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite subjective, quality score remains same, provided the implementation of your HTTPS is same (page speed is intact etc). I have never seen a considerable drop doing this.

As soon as you change the ad, you will have to go through the approval process, that might definitely impact your campaign.